# How to skip a number of iterations of a loop in GDB?

Tags: c, debugging, loops, for-loop, gdb

Suppose I have a loop that will iterate 100 times and I want to skip 50 iterations but I want to continue pressing `next` from there on to see each line.

I don't want to set a breakpoint after the loop, because this way I'll skip all iterations and not only the number I intend to.

Is there a way to do this in GDB? How?

P.S. I don't want keep pressing `next` from start to finish. It's time consuming...

Comment: using break conditions.

Comment: OK. But in my case the given loop is inside a helper function that is in another file. I access the loop using "step" at the line I call the function. How do I set a break condition in a line of another file?

Comment: Now I know: you just need to do this: b filename:numberOfTheLine, for example: b helper.c:70. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Set a breakpoint in the loop and then call **c 50** to continue 50 times

[Debugging with GDB](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_38.html)

> 5.2 Continuing and stepping
>
> continue [ignore-count]
>   c [ignore-count] 
> fg [ignore-count]
>  Resume
>   program execution, at the address where your program last stopped; any
>   breakpoints set at that address are bypassed. The optional argument
>   ignore-count allows you to specify a further number of times to ignore
>   a breakpoint at this location; its effect is like that of ignore (see
>   section Break conditions). The argument ignore-count is meaningful
>   only when your program stopped due to a breakpoint. At other times,
>   the argument to continue is ignored.

Answer (score 12):

You could use conditional break points

```
break <lineno> if i > 50
```

where `i` is the loop index

Answer (score 0):

You can use the condition breakpoint.

syntax:

```
b FileName.extension:lineNumber if varname condition
```

example:

```
b File.c:112 if i == 50
```

Answer (score -8):

In C# for example you can do "continue" to skip iteration. Example of skipping numbers with mod 3 equal 0, so numbers 3, 9, 12, 15 ... will be skipped.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            if (i%3 == 0)
            {
                continue;                    
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time writing this, but my question is about GDB (GNU Debugger).

Comment: the question was about using gdb, not how to code a loop that will skip 50 itterations